# How to solve oracle connector error in DataStage?

Tags: datastage

I am facing a sudden issue in my datastage job. when run the job it eventually aborts/fails and gives below error. whereas this was not happening earlier, I ran the job multiple times and it completed successfully.I have not made any changes.
I am getting this error in my source oracle connector.

following is the error:

```
Oracle_Connector: The connector could not access the oracle server using the specified Username.
Method: OCISessionBegin:OCI_CRED_RDBMS,
Error code:28040, Error message ORA-00000: normal,
successful completion.(CC_OraConnection::verifyConnection, file CC_OraConnection.cpp, line 5,171)
```

Answer (score 1):

The most probable cause is that the password of the Oracle user has expired.